# How to publish 3 webcams in the internet

Tags: webcam, streaming

I have three webcams connected to a PC with Ubuntu.

The endpoints are:

- /dev/video0
- /dev/video1
- /dev/video2

Those are security cameras and I would like the my family to be able to access through internet to the webcam streamings.

I have been reading about RTSP protocol and ngrok as well, but I'm not sure which is the best method.

Can you please guys give me some orientation?

Thanks in advace

Comment: I would use gstreamer or vlc.

Comment: I use `motion` and and tunnel it over ssh. It may (probably) not be the best way, but it's what I know how to do.

Comment: What version of Ubuntu are you using?